# Facebook api offline message send

Tags: facebook, api

How to send a message to a user who is offline using Facebook API?

Comment: have to able to send message in Inbox of friends now....... and also I want to get the messages from my Inbox

Answer (score 1):

Since there's no details, I'm assume you'll be using [PHP-SDK](http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk). So just grant the `publish_stream` permission and use something like:

```
require 'src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'APP_SECRET',
  'cookie' => true,
));
$post_id = $facebook->api("/USER_ID/feed","POST",array("message"=>"Hello Offline!"));
if(!empty($post_id["id"]))
    echo $post_id["id"];
```

Comment: Is that a message or a wall post?

Comment: @manuelpedrera: a wall post, do you think that OP is actually asking for a message to be received on the user inbox?

Comment: This is a good workaround since you cannot send messages via the public Graph API.

Comment: I want this is with some modification, Should i send this message on behalf of my facebook application use... I really need it please give me answer as soon as possibe..

Answer (score 1):

Irrespective of user online or offline, you can not send message to a user. If you have offline_access and read_mailbox permissions you can read mails.

But there are few workaround for this. One is to send a normal email as example@facebook.com. This will work only if that user has enabled Facebook email for the account.

Other-one is to write on their wall. But this is not private.